# Error Unable to copy files settings files from BLT into your repository

Tags: 8

When I try to run `blt sync` I am getting the following error.

> `blt:init:settings`
>
> Hash salt already exists.
> [error]  Unable to copy files settings files from BLT into your repository.
> For troubleshooting guidance and support, see https://docs.acquia.com/blt/support/
> The command failed. This often indicates a problem with your configuration. Review the command output above for more detailed errors, and consider re-running with verbose output for more information.
> [error]  Command `blt:init:settings`  exited with code 1.
> For troubleshooting guidance and support, see https://docs.acquia.com/blt/support/

Answer (score 0):

I got resolved the same problem using the following steps.

1. run the blt sync with -v   `blt sync -vvv`
2. Which will help you to find the cause of the error,

In my case, it was permission for the recipe settings.php file.

So I have to run the **chmod** command *outside* the box, then ssh into the box, delete the database and ran the `blt acsf:init`

After all these I ran the `blt sync` its worked fine.  Hope this will be helpful for those facing the same issue. :)